# Error on array to create a formula

Tags: tables

I'm getting an error on latex and don't understand why..., but it is getting me some error which i don't really understand ... Any hint for me please ? Thank you

```
\[ 
\delta_{s}\bullet \delta_{t} = \left \{ \begin{array}{  } \delta_{st} 
     &  \mbox{ if $ s^{\ast}s = t t^{\ast}$}\\
0    &  \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array} \qquad  (s,t\in S) \right .
\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Add your prologue and file .log. Probabily is dollar sign into a formula with `\[...\]`.

Comment: Also, if you could add a picture of your desired formula, it would be helpful.

Comment: `\begin{array}{  }` is an error you have to specify the column alignments eg `ll` in that argument.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\delta_{s}\bullet \delta_{t} = \left\{ 
        \begin{array}{ll}
\delta_{st} &  \text{if }  s^{\ast}s = t t^{\ast}\\
        0   &  \text{otherwise}
        \end{array} \qquad  (s,t\in S) \right .
\]
\[
\delta_{s}\bullet \delta_{t} = 
        \begin{cases}
\delta_{st} &  \text{if }  s^{\ast}s = t t^{\ast}\\
        0   &  \text{otherwise}
        \end{cases} \qquad  (s,t\in S)
\]
and an alternative considering \textit{Mico} comment and added more vertical space between cases lines:
\[
\delta_{s}\bullet \delta_{t} =
        \begin{cases}
\delta_{st} &  \text{if $s^{\ast}s = t t^{\ast}$}  \\[1ex]
        0   &  \text{otherwise}
        \end{cases} \qquad  (s,t\in S)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You forgot to define columns in your array. IN above you can find two examples: with array, where is used `\text{...}` instead `\mbox` and `cases`, both from `mathtools` package.

**Edit:**
As *Mico* noted in his comment: "... it's preferable to write `\text{if $s^{\ast}s = t t^{\ast}$}`, i.e., use a single \text instruction, as its argument forms a single (syntactical) sentence." This I considered in added third example in MWE.

Comment: there's a spurious space before `if`.

Comment: @Bernard, thank you to observe my typing errors. Now is they are corrected.

Comment: It's not yours, it's in the O.P. I did exactly as you, I suppose: copying and pasting the original code, and concentrating on simplification of the code. You're welcome to point my own (many) typos  ;o)

Comment: +1. in the `cases` environment, I think it's preferable to write `\text{if  $s^{\ast}s = t t^{\ast}$}`, i.e., use a single `\text` instruction, as its argument forms a single (syntactical) sentence.

Comment: @Mico, from point of sentence, it can be preferable.I add suggested as the third case in my answer.